# What Regex would capture everything from ' mark to the end of a line?

Tags: regex

I have a text file that denotes remarks with a single `'`.

Some lines have two quotes but I need to get everything from the first instance of a `'` and the line feed.

```
I AL01                  ' A-LINE                            '091398 GDK 33394178    
         402922 0831850 '                                   '091398 GDK 33394179    
I AL02                  ' A-LINE                            '091398 GDK 33394180    
         400722 0833118 '                                   '091398 GDK 33394181    
I A10A                  ' A-LINE 102                       '  53198 DJ  33394182    
         395335 0832203 '                                  '  53198 DJ  33394183    
I A10B                  ' A-LINE 102                       '  53198 DJ  3339418
```

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
'.*
```

I believe you need the option, Multiline.

Comment: This will capture first instance of character ' and end of last line

Comment: With this you go to the end of the file or the text, not to the end of the line.

Answer (score 129):

The appropriate regex would be the ' char followed by any number of any chars [including zero chars] ending with an end of string/line token:

```
'.*$
```

And if you wanted to capture everything *after* the ' char but not include it in the output, you would use:

```
(?<=').*$
```

This basically says give me all characters that follow the ' char until the end of the line.

**Edit**: It has been noted that $ is implicit when using .* and therefore not strictly required, therefore the pattern:

```
'.*
```

is technically correct, however it is clearer to be specific and avoid confusion for later code maintenance, hence my use of the $. It is my belief that it is always better to declare explicit behaviour than rely on implicit behaviour in situations where clarity could be questioned.

Comment: The $ is unnecessary. The dot will stop at the end of the line under normal circumstances.

Comment: unnecessary - but proper for what he wants to do.  It serves as a reminder later that it is expecting everything from ' to the end of the line

Comment: @balabaster: I did not say that it was wrong. ;-) It was just a footnote.

Comment: @Tomalak: Wasn't trying to imply you were wrong by any means, was just clarifying my reasoning for my choice of using $ rather than not.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: +1 for including how to include everything after the character in question, instead of always including it.

Comment: (?<=').*$ is actually correct answer to what op is asking, capture after, not with. This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 33):

```
'.*$
```

Starting with a single quote (`'`), match any character (`.`) zero or more times (`*`) until the end of the line (`$`).

Comment: This answer is a great example of how to break down the logic behind what a command, nice and clear!

Answer (score 20):

When I tried '.* in windows (Notepad ++) it would match everything after first ' until end of last line.

To capture everything until end of that line I typed the following:

```
'.*?\n
```

This would only capture everything from ' until end of that line.

Answer (score 12):

In your example I'd go for the following pattern:

```
'([^\n]+)$
```

use multiline and global options to match all occurences.

To include the linefeed in the match you could use:

```
'[^\n]+\n
```

But this might miss the last line if it has no linefeed.

For a single line, if you don't need to match the linefeed I'd prefer to use:

```
'[^$]+$
```

Comment: Had trouble with this suggestion with golang's regex. `'[^\n]+` was needed instead of `'[^\n]+$`. See https://play.golang.org/p/EemihqdIMSl

Answer (score 5):

This will capture everything up to the ' in backreference 1 - and everything after the ' in backreference 2.  You may need to escape the apostrophes though depending on language (\')

```
/^([^']*)'?(.*)$/
```

Quick modification: if the line doesn't have an ' - backreference 1 should still catch the whole line.

```
^ - start of string
([^']*) - capture any number of not ' characters
'? - match the ' 0 or 1 time
(.*) - capture any number of characters
$ - end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/Jjc2xR/1

```
/(\w*\(Hex\): w*)(.*?)(?= |$)/gm
```

I'm sure this one works, it will capture de hexa serial in the badly structured text multilined bellow

```
     Space Reservation: disabled
         Serial Number: wCVt1]IlvQWv
   Serial Number (Hex): 77435674315d496c76515776
               Comment: new comment
```

I'm a eternal newbie in regex but I'll try explain this one

(\w*(Hex): w*) : Find text in line where string contains "Hex: "

(.*?) This is the second captured text and means everything after

(?= |$) create a limit that is the space between = and the |

So with the second group, you will have the value

Comment: That's not the question, is it ?