# Javascript to search and replace using RegEx - not working in iMacros

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I am trying to perform a search and replace in a string using javascript.
An example of the string looks like this:
Parameter 1 = xxx
where xxx are some characters that I want to replace

The RegEx needs to find everything after "Parameter 1 = " until the end of the line, which is xxx.
The javascript then needs to replace xxx it with yyy, where yyy are some other characters.
For example,
Parameter 1 = 42 => Parameter 1 = 11

I found the regex for this on this forum ([What Regex would capture everything from ' mark to the end of a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830855/what-regex-would-capture-everything-from-mark-to-the-end-of-a-line)). Modifying it for my case would be:

```
(?<=Parameter 1 = ).*$
```

I then tried the following java script:

```
var str="Parameter 1 = 42";`
var res=str.replace(/(?<=Parameter 1 =).*$/, "11");
alert(res);
```

However, that gives me an error when I run it using iMacros:

```
SyntaxError: invalid regexp group, line 6 (Error code: -991)
```

p.s. I do not understand why my question has been marked as [duplicate] and closed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
var str="Parameter 1 = 42";
var res=str.replace(/(?<=Parameter 1 =).*$/, "11");
console.log(res);
```

And if lookbehind aren't supported you can do this:

```js
var str = "Parameter 1 = 42";
var res = str.replace(/(Parameter 1 =)(.*)$/, "$163");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @HoLoN,

Thank you for your answer. However, your solution also gives me an error:

SyntaxError: invalid regexp group, line 6 (Error code: -991)

(I am running the javascript in iMacros)

Comment: the snippet is correct, try `run snippet`

Comment: @HoLoN, Yes, the snippet works. However, it doesn't work in iMacros (v. 8.9.7 and 
Firefox Developer Edition (Portable) v. 55.0b2 (64-bit)). I get the Syntax error above: "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group, line 6 (Error code: -991)"

Comment: That's because your regex engine doesn't support lookbehind groups.

Comment: Oh. Is there some other way of solving this in iMacros? Maybe rewriting the RegEx somehow so that it is compatible with iMacros RegEx engine?

Comment: My answer got updated

Comment: Thank you again! However, when I run the snippet, I get Parameter 1=1, instead of Parameter 1=11. I get the same incorrect result in iMacros but w/o the Syntax error :-)!!

I don't understand the RegEx, but by trial and error, I found that var "res = str.replace(/^(Parameter 1 =)(.*)$/, "$01yyy")" worked. For example if yyy=11, I get Parameter 1=11. Is this correct, should I use $01 + new yyy value? 
(Sorry for being a newbie at this but how does the $01 "prefix" work?)

Comment: Ok that good now, could you accept/upvote the answser ?

Comment: I see that you corrected your answer. Can you please explain how the $1 "prefix" works?
Also, do you know who to contact for clarification on why my question was downvoted, marked as duplicate and closed?

I upvoted your answer, but it still shows as 0 (apparently because my own score <15). Sorry!

Comment: $x make a reference to the captured group in regex with x starting at 1.